Integral of a function by bounding between two step-functions
Take two step-functions $t(x)$ and $s(x)$ such that non-negative monotic $f(x)$ lies between them. $s(x) \leq f(x) \leq t(x)$.  Then,
$$\int_a^b s(x)\leq I \leq \int_a^b t(x) \implies a(S) \leq I \leq a(T)$$
I don't understand when it says  that if there is only such $I$ satisfying the inequality then I is the integral of f(x). Because between the two step-functions $t(x)$ and $s(x)$, any function lying between them will have the area value between these two integrals, but the equation says there is only one such number, so all the functions between these two would have the same area??

You have to consider all step functions $s,t$ such that $s(x) \leq f(x) \leq t(x)$. I only one $I$ then $f$ is integrable with integral $I$.

Area of ordinate set $Q$  of $f(x)$ would be $I$. How do i show using the inequalities that $a(Q)$ is equal to the area of $Q$ minus the graph of $f(x)$.
